# File input without button

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagick, jquery-file-upload

I've been trying to implement image upload with the following requirements:

1. Drag and drop
2. Display dropped image in a popup with option to resize image
3. Upload image after preview and resize

I'm trying to restrict my options to either [bass jobsen's jqueryupload](https://github.com/bassjobsen/jqueryupload).
Using this plugin, I've so far managed to do something similar to this:

```
$('document).on('drop', '#drop_area', function(event) {
    var file_input = $('<input>').attr({type: 'file', 'id': 'hidden_file_input'});
    $('body').append(file_input.hide());

    var file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
    var file_reader = new FileReader();

    file_reader.onloadend = function(e) {
       var src = file_reader.result;
       file_upload_preview();
    }
    file_reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
    $file_input[0][files][0] = file; // this line only works 5% of the time
});

function file_upload_preview() {
   self.modal_show('/modal/preview', function(e) { // render popup using file /modal/preview.html
          // do image crop options
   });
   doUpload();
}

function doUpload() {
   var file_input = $('#upload_form_id');
   var file = file_input.get(0).files[0]; // throws error because of $file_input[0][files][0] = file; not working
   var url = '/tmp/uploads';
   var data = {
       'x' : file_input.data('x') // image resize dimension
       // add others, etc.
   };
   // do validations
   file_input.upload(url, data, function(json) { // jqueryupload start
      var res = JSON.parse(json); // throws error if the above code doesn't
   });
}
```

I am getting multiple errors with this code:

1. The line `$file_input[0][files][0] = file;` will not always work for some reason
2. If #1 does not happen, another error is thrown when trying to upload: "Can not process empty Imagick object"

What is the best and sure way I can set the value of `file_input` by drag and drop instead of choosing the file? Also is it possible to implement what I need using this plugin?

Comment: Shouldn't `var file_reader = new FileReader;` be `var file_reader = new FileReader();`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missed that when typing the sample code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues at `javascript` at Question

- `$file_input[0]files[0]` should select `File` object, instead of `$file_input[0][files][0]`, where brackets surrounding `files` property is syntax error;
- it is not possible to set a `File` object to the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object of an `<input type="file">` element, where `$file_input[0][files][0] = file; // this line only works 5% of the time` attempts to set dropped file `var file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];` as value of `.files[0]` at dynamically created `<input type="file">` element `var file_input = $('<input>').attr({type: 'file', 'id': 'hidden_file_input'});`;
- `var file_input = $('#upload_form_id')` is not `#drop_area` element where files were dropped by user

---

Edit, Updated

> 1. Drag and drop file to main.html 2. Add file to rendered popup - preview.html 3. upload

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    #dropzone {
      display: block;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 36px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function handleDrop(event) {
      var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
      // copy dropped file
      // note, not necessary though requirement
      var copy = file.slice();
      // create objectURL of `copy`
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(copy);
      // open `preview.html`
      var preview = window
                    .open("preview.html"
                         , "preview"
                         , "width=400,height=400,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");
      // set `img` at `preview.html` to `copy` 
      // at `DOMContenetLoaded` event of `peview
      $(preview).on("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
        // set `img` `src` to `url`:`copy` of `file` at `preview.html`
        $(e.target.body).find("img").attr("src", url);
        // remove `disabled` for ability to close `preview`
        $("button:eq(1)").removeAttr("disabled")
      });
      $("button:eq(1)").on("click", function() {
        // close `preview`
        preview.close();
        // revoke objectURL
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        $(this).attr("disabled", true)
        // remove `disabled` at previous `button`
        // for ability to upload file
        .prev("button").removeAttr("disabled")
      });
      $("button:eq(0)").on("click", function() {
        // create `FormData` object to `POST`
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", file);
        console.log(data.get("file"));
        $(this).attr("disabled", true)
          // do ajax stuff, post file
          // $.ajax({
          //    type:"POST",
          //    processData:false,
          //    data: data
          // })
      });

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dropzone" 
  ondragenter="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();" 
  ondragover="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();" 
  ondrop="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();handleDrop(event)">
    Drop files
  </div>
  <button disabled="">upload</button>
  <button disabled="">close preview</button>
</body>

</html>
```

preview.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="">
  </body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Cij0bUojvfhUNZjRw4FM?p=preview

Comment: I'm trying to pass the file into a dynamically created input file which is added onto my $('#upload_form_id') form which is the popup and not the actual drop area. Since this isn't possible, what can you suggest instead in order to display the dropped image on a different popup screen?

Comment: How is the "popup" screen rendered? No `javascript` at Question appears to include processing of a "popup". You can call `FileReader` with dropped file object `var file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];` and pass dropped file object to `doUpload`

Comment: I render it using a separate file

Comment: Not clear what requirement is? You have available dropped `File` object at `var file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];`, you can pass the same variable  reference to other functions, or create a copy of the file to pass to other functions

Comment: Yeah, but I need to add file as part of view.

Comment: Where should file be passed to? What is "view"? You can pass `src` to `doUpload()` , e.g., `function doUpload(file) {console.log(file)}`, within `.onloadened` function call `doUpload(src)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117514/discussion-between-user1597438-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

I think,the cause of the error that `readAsDataUrl()` is async operation, and you must wait for it to finish before you do the rest of the work.
You can try the following code:

```
file_reader.onload = function(e) {
    if(reader.readyState == FileReader.DONE) //You can remove this if not needed
        alert(file.name);
    }
}
```